# Continuous functions take convergent sequences into convergent sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm reviewing some concepts regarding metric spaces, and I would like to know someone's opinion if the following proof is technically correct.

But first lets the denote: $X$ is a metric space and $d_X$ is the metric function defined on X. Moreover, the set $B_{\varepsilon}(x_0)=\{x\in X | d_X(x,x_0)<\varepsilon\}$ is the open ball of radius $\varepsilon$ and centered in $x_0$.

**The claim is**: Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces and consider the function $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$. Then $f$ is continuous at $x_0\in X$ if, and only if, for each sequence $x_i\in X$ such that $x_i\to x_0$, we have $f(x_i)\to f(x_0)$.

**My proof**: Let $x_0\in X$ be a fixed point and $x_i\in X$ be an arbitrary sequence such that $x_i\to x_0$. Because $f$ is continuous, we have: for a given $\varepsilon >0$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $f(B_{\delta}(x_0))\subset B_{\varepsilon}(f(x_0))$. Moreover, since $x_i\to x_0$, for the above $\delta>0$, $\exists i_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, for each $i\geq i_0$ we have $x_i \in B_{\delta}(x_0)$. Hence, $f(x_i)\in B_{\varepsilon}(f(x_0))$, and we conclude: $f(x_i)\to f(x_0)$.

Reciprocally, lets suppose by contradiction that $f$ is not continuous at $x_0\in X$. That implies the existence of a $\varepsilon>0$, such that for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$, we can find $x_i\in X$ such that $d_X(x_i,x_0)<1/n$, but $d_Y(f(x_i),f(x_0))\geq\varepsilon$, i.e., $f(x_i)\in f(B_{1/n}(x_0))$, but $f(x_i)\notin B_{\varepsilon}(f(x_0))$, which is a contradicton with the hypostesis.
$\blacksquare$

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should denote your sequence by something like $(x_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\subset X$. On the end of the proof it should be $d_X(x_i,x_0)<1/i$, later you also mixed $1/n$ with $1/i$. You also should be more clear about why the last statement contradicts the hypothesis.

Besides this, the proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and tips!

Comment: If this answer was usefull would you consider accepting it please?

Comment: Yes, of course! I just did it. Thank you again.